# Independent random variables and ther CDF with joint distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ be three independent random variables uniformly distributed over the interval (0, 1).

(a) What is the joint CDF $F_{X_1, X_2}$?

(b) Compute $P\left(X_{1} > X_{2} + X_{3}\right)$.

**My attempts at solution**:

(a)Because they are independent, the joint density for $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ can be separated and since they are both uniformly distributed over the range 0 to 1, the marginal densities are simply 1.  $$F_{X_1, X_2} = \int_{0}^{b}\int_{0}^{a} f_{X_1, X_2}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) dx_{1}dx_{2} = \int_{0}^{b}\int_{0}^{a} f_{X_1}\left(x_{1}\right) f_{X_2}\left(x_{2}\right) dx_{1}dx_{2} = \int_{0}^{b}\int_{0}^{a} dx_{1}dx_{2} = ab$$ for $a,b \in \left(0, 1\right)$. Is this the correct answer or am I missing something?

(b) Let $Z=X_2 + X_3$. We need to compute $P\left(X_{1} > X_{2} + X_{3}\right)$, so I thought the way to go about this is by using the convolution idea, but I am not sure if this is right.
$$ P\left(X_{1} > X_{2} + X_{3}\right) = P\left(X_{1} > Z\right) = P\left(Z < X_1\right) = \int_{R}F_{X_1}\left(x_1 - x_2\right) f_{X_2}\left(x_2\right) dx_2$$

We know that the density of $X_1$ is simply 1 over the interval $\left(0, 1\right)$, and so the CDF $F_{X_1}\left(x_1 - x_2\right)$ is just $\int_{0}^{x_1-x_2} d_{x_1} = x_1-x_2$. Similarly, the density of $X_2$ is just 1, so the integral above for the answer gives $$ \int_{R}F_{X_1}\left(x_1 - x_2\right) f_{X_2}\left(x_2\right) dx_2 = \int_{0}^{1} \left(x_1-x_2\right) dx_2 = x_1 - \frac{x_{1}^{2}}{2} $$
I am not very confident with this, but I am not sure if it is completely wrong either. Please let me know!

Comment: It looks right to me. Did you eventually find out if it's correct?

Comment: So for part (a), my answer was right for the interval $0 \leq a, b \leq 1$, but this is just one part of the piecewise density defined over all space. When only one of the two variables is in the interval $[0, 1]$ the density is just that variable, either $a$ or $b$. Then, 0 otherwise. part (b) is simply $\int_{0}^{1}{ \int_{0}^{1-x_3}{\int_{x_2 + x_3}^{1}{ dx_1}  dx_2} dx_3} $

Comment: Great, thanks!!